# Is there any way to format a complete python buffer in emacs with a key press?

Tags: python, emacs, formatter

I am looking for any way to have Emacs format a Python buffer by hitting a few keys.  By format, I mean:

1. Replace tabs with 4 spaces
2. Wrap all long lines correctly at 79 chars.  This includes wrapping & concatenating long strings, wrapping long comments, wrapping lists, function headers, etc.
3. Unrelated, but when I hit enter, it'd be nice if the cursor was tabbed in automatically.

In general I'd like to just format everything according to PEP 8.

I've looked for a pretty printer / code beautifier / code formatter for Python to run the buffer through, but can't find an open source one.

My .emacs is [here](http://dpaste.com/hold/81704/).

For those who are going to answer "You don't need a formatter for Python, it's beautiful by the nature of the language," I say to you that this is not correct.  In real software systems, comments should be auto-wrapped for you, strings are going to be longer than 79 characters, tab levels run 3+ deep.  Please just help me solve my issue directly without some philosophical discussion about the merits of formatting Python source.

Comment: Wrap at at 79 characters?  That's just silly.  It's not 1985 anymore; nobody is programming on an 80x25 screen.

Comment: @Glenn, PEP 8 specifies 79, so 79 it is.  It's nice to have it viewable anywhere, and if I do need to login remotely via a shell to change something in production, 79 is perfect.

Comment: I don't mindlessly follow braindamaged PEPs.  Targetting code for 80-column terminals in 2009 is plainly absurd, and makes code ugly and unreadable.

Comment: I like 80 column limits.  Not only can I easily fit multiple windows of code next to each other, but when I print it out, it still formats nicely.

Comment: 80 characters makes a lot of sense. It's wide enough to be useful, but (when enforced) stops lines becoming so wide that they are unreadable and the person viewing them has to constantly stretch and shrink their browser window. One of the great things about Python is its enforced formatting rules. 80 chars helps, but having to format it yourself is a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change tabs into spaces and fill comments at the same time, you can use this command:

```
(defun my-format-python-text ()
  "untabify and wrap python comments"
  (interactive)
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward comment-start nil t)
    (call-interactively 'fill-paragraph)
    (forward-line 1)))
```

Which you can bind to the key of your choice, presumably like so:

```
(eval-after-load "python"
  '(progn
     (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
     (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "<f4>") 'my-format-python-text)))
```

Note the setting of the `RET` key to automatically indent.

If you wanted to all tabs with spaces with just built-in commands, this is a possible sequence:

```
C-x h           ;; mark-whole-buffer
M-x untabify    ;; tabs->spaces
```

To get the fill column and tab width to be what you want, add to your .emacs:

```
(setq fill-column 79)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
```

Arguably, the tab-width should be set to 8, depending on how other folks have indented their code in your environment (8 being a default that some other editors have).  If that's the case, you could just set it to 4 in the `'python-mode-hook`.  It kind of depends on your environment.

Comment: Also, M-q will wrap long comments.  (I believe the lisp command is "fill-region".)

Comment: `M-q` actually `'fill-paragraph`, which is what I used in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

About your point 3:

> Unrelated, but when I hit enter, it'd
>   be nice if the cursor was tabbed in
>   automatically.

My emacs Python mode does this by default, apparently.  It's simply called [python-mode](https://launchpad.net/python-mode/)...

Comment: The first revision of my answer had that same point, but then I noticed it was my own copy (as opposed to the one that ships with Emacs).

Answer (score 1):

Using [Spacemacs' Python layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/python#automatic-buffer-formatting-on-save) with default bindings:

The sequence `, =` will run `yapfify-buffer` to impose PEP8 formatting on the entire buffer.

You can set

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
  (python :variables python-enable-yapf-format-on-save t)))
```

to enable automating reformatting on save.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid tab characters in your file is to not insert them at all.  The following statement will always insert the correct number of spaces, rather than inserting tab characters

```
;; Turn off tab insertion in favor of space insertion
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

I see you have this in your .emacs file already

Answer (score 0):

The autopep8 and the emacs wrapper for it should fulfill your desire.. https://github.com/paetzke/py-autopep8.el